# java static initialization of a class will print what is inside the constructor

Tags: java, static

```
    public class StaticInitialization{
        //This without the static does not print anything
        static Table table = new Table();
        public static void main(String[] args) { }
    }
    public class Table{
       static Bowl bowl1 = new Bowl(1); 
       static Bowl bowl2 = new Bowl(2);
       Table() { 
            System.out.println("Table()"); 
            bowl2.f1(1); 
       } 
    }
    public class Bowl{
        Bowl(int marker) { 
             System.out.println("Bowl(" + marker + ")"); 
        } 
        void f1(int marker) { 
             System.out.println("f1(" + marker + ")"); 
         } 
    }
```

My question is why the Table without the static does not print anything. But with static it prints.

I tried instatiating it inside of main and it prints. The first time it prints the staic objects as well bowl1, bowl2 due to sharing of static properties.

The second without the static properties.

Are there any use cases that this can become useful?

Comment: Thisi is what it prints with static.

static Table table = new Table();


Bowl(1)
Bowl(2)
Table()
f1(1)

Comment: Because you are never instantiating anything in `main()`.

Comment: what you see above it has 4 lines of print statements. So it prints my question is when i remove the static from table see comment in code it does not print.

Comment: @EJP ok you were right i tried in main. I need to instantiate the StaticInitialization, in order for it to instantiate the property Duh. Played! Thanks, thsi is now understood.

Comment: If you have a new question, please post a new question. Changing the original question makes existing answers useless.I rolled back the question to the original state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take this as example:

```
public class StaticInitialization{
    // table1 is initialized when the class StaticInitialization is loaded
    static Table table1 = new Table();

    // table2 is initialized when a new instance of StaticInitialization is created
    Table table2 = new Table();

    ...
}
```

Since you never create an object of class `StaticInitialization` the variable `table2` is never initialized and the corresponding `new Table()` is never executed.

Comment: Is there some good use case for such an example? I find it a little hard maintainig code that looks like this.

Comment: It is more common to use this together with final to define constants. Typically, an initialization does not have side effects (like printing something).

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class StaticInitialization{
        /* Here static variable get initialized 
           when class is loaded and constructor of Table will get invoked */
        static Table table = new Table();
        public static void main(String[] args) { }
    }
```

If you remove static then it will become instance variable and only get initialized when you create instance of Table

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple.  If `table` is a non-`static` member of `StaticInitialization`:

```
 Table table = new Table();
```

it only gets initialized  (meaning the `Table()` constructor gets called)  if an instance of `StaticInitialization` is created (that is, `new StaticInitialization()` gets done somewhere).

If `table` is a `static` member:

```
static Table table = new Table();
```

it gets initialized  when the `StaticInitialization` class gets loaded--which always happens because `StaticInitialization` contains your `main` method.